# Binding Date value change Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I wanted to achieve that once i click the different date my data input will be change depending that date they had. but when i tried the trigger but it wont change any.

```js
asOfDate: any;

ngOnInit(){
  this.fg = this.fb.group({
    arrayForm: this.fb.array([this.CreateList()])
  })
}
CreateList():FormGroup{
  return this.fb.group({
    total: [],
    name: [],
    remarks: [],
    asOfDate: [new Date().toISOString().substring(0, 10)]
  })
}

openDialog(index: number){
  const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogComponent, {});
  dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((result) => {
    (this.fg.get('arrayForm') as FormArray).at(index).patchValue(result)
    this.asOfDate = result;
  });
}

dateTrigger(trigger: MatSelectChange){
  this.asOfDate = trigger.value;
}
```

```html
<td>
  <input matInput type="date" formControlName="asOfDate" class="form-control" (selectionChange)="dateTrigger($event)">
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can listen to the valueChanges event if you want to use reactive form features

```js
ngOnInit(){
  this.fg = this.fb.group({
   arrayForm:this.fb.array([this.CreateList()])
  })

  merge(...this.fg.get('arrayForm').controls.map(control => control.valueChanges))
    .subscribe(item => this.asOfDate = item.asOfDate);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `change` event (on blur) or `input` event (on keydown) in order to receive events from inputs.

```
<input matInput type="date" formControlName="asOfDate" class="form-control" (input)="dateTrigger($event)">
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because `this.asOfDate` is not connected to your form as far I can see.

You have to update the value on the formGroup via `patchValue`:

```
dateTrigger(trigger:MatSelectChange){
   this.asOfDate = this.fg.get('arrayForm').at(0).get('asOfDate').patchValue(trigger.value);
}
```